# calling mysql procedure dynamically from matlab

Tags: mysql, matlab

I am  calling a mysql stored procedure with 2 interger input arguments from matlab in a for loop and getting error. the matlab code is:

```
conn = database('mysqltestconn','root','4266');
for i = 1:7
    for j=1:7
        if i~=j
            sqlquery = 'call reguexp(''i'',''j'')';
            cursor = fetch(conn,sqlquery);
        end
    end
end
```

name of stored procedure is 'reguexp' and it have to input parameters.  please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not into MySQL queries but it looks like you want to pass the values of i and j in your regular expression. If so, you should convert the integer values to a string using num2str(i):

```
sqlquery = ['call reguexp(',num2str(i),',',num2str(j),')'];
```

You may check the string by printing it on each iteration using disp()
(By the way it is also possible to avoid the nested loops and replace it by a vectorised approach - looks more MATLABish :) )

Cheers,
Eli

Comment: thankyou for your help,
well i want to pass the integer not the string, like for example when i=1 and j starts to iterate, first it should tell to mysql that input in (1,2), then (1,3),(1,4),...(1,7) then (2,1),(2,3),(2,4),....(2,7) then (3,1),(3,2),.....\

Comment: hi, that is what you accomplish by using num2str()...it converts the values of your integer variables i and j into strings.
for example if i=1 and j=2 then your string would look like
'call reguexp(1,2)'. this string is then passed to mysql where it gets evaluated. fetch() cannot handle integers as an input for the expression argument:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/fetch.html?searchHighlight=fetch#inputarg_sqlquery

Comment: thankyou so much,, you are absolutely right. i tried this solution and its working now. :)